# Fatal error: Class 'Event' not found in /bootstrap/start.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am getting Fatal error: Class 'Event' not found in /home/vagrant/Projects/MyProject/bootstrap/start.php on line 41

This is line 41:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {
    // some action
});
```

I tried namespacing like so:

```
Laravel\Event::listen
```

But that does not work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to add your event listeners in `bootstrap/start.php`. The purpose of that file is to create the Laravel application and detect the enviroment. If you want to have event listeners that are global you can create a `app/events.php` file where your can place your code:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {
    // some action
});
```

And then include the file within the `app/start/global.php` like so:

```
require app_path().'/events.php';
```

Comment: ServiceProviders would also be great for that purpse. But nice and simple solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `bootstrap/start.php` is the file where the laravel application instance is created. It means that all the classes including the `Event class` is instantiated after that file is loaded. So if you try to access the `Event class` there, the error is thrown since that class has not been instantiated.

For the quick fix, you can register your event in `app/start/global.php` but as @Bogdan said, it is not ideal to register your events there. You can either create dedicated file for event listeners and `require` that file in `app/start/global.php` or you can create service providers.